# Sidebar Block the scroll and all the page

Tags: css, vuetify.js

I created a sidebar that overlay the rest of the page while activate.
I want to be able to manipulate the page whether the sidebar is activate or not.
I'am using Vuetify .
Here is my code. https://www.codeply.com/p/mXNElmC56h 
I think it can be done with css.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to do this. The "hide-overlay" prop.

```
<v-navigation-drawer
    v-model="drawer"
    fixed
    temporary
    hide-overlay
  >
</v-navigation-drawer>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/navigation-drawers/#api), just remove the `temporary` props from the `<v-navigation-drawer/>` element.

```html
<v-navigation-drawer v-model="drawer" absolute>
  ...
</v-navigation-drawer>
```

Here is a sample [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-lovelace-uzevb?file=/src/components/Playground.vue).

Also, please take note that according to the docs, `temporary` prop will always be applied on smaller screens.

Comment: Yes i agree but when i click in the page the navigation drawer still over the page.